# How to insert element into specific array position?

Tags: php, arrays

I can't use `array_splice` since my element is an object. Instead of inserting it as a whole, it inserts it field by field.

**P.S.**

I was inserting as Leigh said:

array_splice($original, 2, 0, $obj);

Comment: Can you elaborate on `object`? Can you just cast it using `(array)`?

Comment: @Martin I don't know what is "elaborate". I have a 'Page' class and an array of pages. I just want to take page from one position and put it into the other. Unbelieveable PHP couldn't do it!

Comment: @SuzanCioc please edit the original question and include your code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass your object directly to `array_splice` you will get the behaviour you describe.

I think you are doing this:

```
$original = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$obj = new Object;

array_splice($original, 2, 0, $obj);
```

When you should be doing this:

```
array_splice($original, 2, 0, array($obj));
```

This way your object will be inserted as a whole, instead of the individual fields being inserted.